# Update function in WP8 app as the update function in XNA

Tags: windows-phone-8, xna

I need to know that 
**if there is an update function that calls automatically it self as the XNA have a update function.**
if NO
then please tell me how can I call a function again within 50ms?

I want to update the UI of my WP8 app after every 50ms.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `DispatcherTimer` for this purpose.

**Example**

First create the `DispatcherTimer` variable in your code-behind:

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
```

Then in NavigatedTo event attach a handler for the `Tick` event:

```
timer.Tick += YourTickHandlerMethod;
```

And also set the update interval, 50 ms in your case:

```
timer.Interval = new TimeSpan( 0, 0, 0, 0, 50);
```

Now, just call `timer.Start();` and the `YourTickHandlerMethod` will run periodically, in which you can perform any UI related actions you need. A convinient thing about `DispatcherTimer` is that it will run the Tick handler method on the UI thread, so you don't need to worry if you do have access to it.